# Compare date in aspx page

Tags: asp.net, date

I am trying to compare current date with a date from on database MySQL.

```
ImageUrl='<%#(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("myDate").ToString()) ? "padlock.gif" : 
          Eval("myDate") > DateTime.Now ? "redbul.gif")%>'
```

I wrote above part but i get error as:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS1003: Syntax error, ':' expected
```

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conditional operator needs the `:` because it indicates the `Or` part, so what is taken if the condition returned `false`. Try this:

```
'<%# String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("myDate").ToString()) ? "padlock.gif" : 
      (DateTime)Eval("myDate") > DateTime.Now ? "redbul.gif" : "FallBackImage.gif" %>'
```

Replace `"FallBackImage.gif"` with the image that should be taken if neither `myDate` is null or empty nor `myDate` is `> DateTime.Now`.

Comment: thank you, now I have this new error *Compiler Error Message: CS0019: Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'System.DateTime'*

Comment: @ChevyMarkSunderland: try to cast it to `DateTime`,`Eval` returns object.